# How can I get a Folder Action Applescript to update a record in a Filemaker server database?

Tags: macos, applescript, filemaker

I want to be able to update our Filemaker Pro server databases (FMS 16) to document when we receive uploads on our OS X (10.6.8) FTP server.

I have done some BASH Shell scripting and some simple Applescripts in the past but I am not well versed on SQL queries, PHP, cURL, etc... So any direction would be helpful.  Using a folder action calling an applescript is what I have been researching but I am not sure how to get Applescript to update the remote database. Is there is a better way to handle this?

I was looking into the following code I found here on StackOverflow but it is for Filemaker Pro Application on the same machine and it assumes the application is open and open to a specific table.

```
on sendDataToFM(FileNameWithExtension, ClipLength)
    tell application "FileMaker Pro"
        show (every record of current table whose cell "File Name" = FileNameWithExtension)
        repeat with i from 1 to (count record)
            set cell "CLIP LENGTH" of (record i) to ClipLength
        end repeat
    end tell
end sendDataToFM
```

Comment: AppleScript can talk directly only to local applications. You may be able to connect indirectly through another application/language that can access the served DB. Do you have FileMaker Pro installed on the computer where the watched folder is?

Comment: See also: https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/16/en/restapi/

Comment: @michael.hor257k Unfortunately, the FTP server OS is too old to run a filemaker client version that is compatible with our active Filemaker Server. I will check out tat link, Thanks!!!

Comment: +1 Michael. Use AppleScript to call bash which will curl post record into database using FileMaker rest API